# how to place admob interstitial ad banner correctly to avoid accidental click warning?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob

i currently have a few apps that have admob integrated... the interstitial ad loads and shows when the app opens and then it shows another ad every minute or so.... i didn't know that there was anything wrong with this as i got my code directly from google and had help online putting it in my app..... it looks like it is currently set to show every set amount of seconds...... but i recently got a warning from admob saying that interstitial should not show up randomly or when the app first loads and they should only show after at least 4 clicks or when a user changes activities....

im not sure how to implement this in my current code correctly as the only example i can find on google is the one i am currently using..... and i don't want to risk getting my account banned by trying different codes the wrong way... would anyone be able to explain and give an example on one activity so i can implement is correctly across my apps....

im not sure the best way to fix it but the best way i can personally think to fix this is to have a screen that says "please wait loading ad...." that appears after 4 every 4 clicks and shows for abut 5 seconds before showing the ad.... after the user closes the ad the app would resume....

or is it better to place the ad between activities and how would i do that properly?

there may be a better way to due this but i have NO IDEA at all.... any help would be much appreciated

you can see what google says about implementing interstitial ads here - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201350?hl=en

here is one of my activities

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

    TabHost tabHost;
    String SearchBaar;
    Boolean search_url = false;
    String searchurl;
    static String about_us;
    static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    static int id = 0, id_for_accept = 0, id_for_webview = 0;
    private final float LOW_LEVEL = 0.75f;
    private final float MEDIUM_LEVEL = 1.0f;
    private final float HIGH_LEVEL = 1.5f;
    private final float X_HIGH_LEVEL = 2.0f;
    private final float XX_HIGH_LEVEL = 3.0f;
    float level;
    int width;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_INSERTIAL = "ca-app-pub-4075500144464557/8781418018";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        level = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        main_layout();

    }

    public void main_layout() {
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_bar_main);


        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        blink();


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        // Get TabHost Refference
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;


        /************* TAB1 ************/
        // Create Intents to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("HOME")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        /************* TAB2 ************/
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Beats.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("BUY BEATS")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        /************* TAB3 ************/
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Membership.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("MEMBERSHIP")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        /************* TAB4 ************/
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Soundkits.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("SOUND KITS")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        if (level <= LOW_LEVEL) {
            System.out.println("LEVEL " + level);
            // do something here

            if (width >= 600 && width < 800) { // it is for 7" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 95;

            } else if (width >= 800) { // it is for 10" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 80;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 80;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 80;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 80;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 80;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 100;

            } else {

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 60;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 60;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 60;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 60;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 60;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 75;
            }

        } else if (level <= MEDIUM_LEVEL) {

            System.out.println("LEVEL " + level);

            if (width >= 600 && width < 800) { // it is for 7" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 120;

            } else if (width >= 800) { // it is for 10" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 130;

            } else {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
            }

            // do smoothing here

        } else if (level <= HIGH_LEVEL) {
            // do something here

            if (width >= 600 && width < 800) { // it is for 7" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 105;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 105;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 105;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 105;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 105;
//                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 135;

            } else if (width >= 800) { // it is for 10" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 115;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 115;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 115;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 115;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 115;
//                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 145;

            } else {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 90;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 90;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 90;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 90;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 90;
//                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 120;
            }

            System.out.println("LEVEL " + level);
        } else if (level <= X_HIGH_LEVEL) {

            if (width >= 600 && width < 800) { // it is for 7" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 140;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 140;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 140;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 140;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 140;
                // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 170;

            } else if (width >= 800) { // it is for 10" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 180;

            } else {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
            }

            // do something here

            System.out.println("LEVEL " + level);
        } else if (level <= XX_HIGH_LEVEL || level > XX_HIGH_LEVEL) {
            // do something here

            if (width >= 600 && width < 800) { // it is for 7" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 170;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 170;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 170;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 170;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 170;
                // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 200;

            } else if (width >= 800) { // it is for 10" Tablet

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 190;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 190;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 190;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 190;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 190;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 215;

            } else {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
                //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 180;
            }

            System.out.println("LEVEL " + level);
        }

        TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        TabWidget widget = host.getTabWidget();
        View v = widget.getChildAt(1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        tv.setTextSize(13);

        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

            View v1 = widget.getChildAt(i);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#424242")); // unselected

            TextView tv1 = (TextView) v1.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

            // center text
            ((TextView) tv1).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            // wrap text
            ((TextView) tv1).setSingleLine(false);

            tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tv1.setTextSize(13);
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#36ace3")); // selected


    }




    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        // /************ Called when tab changed *************/

        TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        TabWidget widget = host.getTabWidget();


        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = widget.getChildAt(i);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#424242")); // unselected
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tv.setTextSize(13);
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#36ace3")); // selected

        View v = widget.getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

        // center text
        ((TextView) tv).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // wrap text
        ((TextView) tv).setSingleLine(false);

        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        tv.setTextSize(13);

    }

//    public void switchTab(int tab) {
//        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
//
//    }

    private void blink() {

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INSERTIAL);
        //
        // // Create ad request.
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequestinsertial = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        //
        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequestinsertial);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {

                    interstitial.show();
                }

            }

        });

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        blink();

                    }

                });

            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

thanks ahead of time for any help advice or examples!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not following Admob's Interstitial ad guidance, you are displaying ads randomly here:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(120000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                blink();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

You are loading Interstitial 120 seconds after you call blink() method. Admob says that you should load ads only between activities or actions, but at this point where the ad is loaded the user can be in the middle of something, witch leads to accidental clicks.

I recommend you to load ads only after one click or when some process has finished, and you can do it from anywhere in the code as follows:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
);
```

To learn more about that go to this [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287).